# how to install prestashop in another localhost

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using `prestashop 1.6` from last 6 months. previously i installed prestashop in `localhost` change the front end view as per my requirement. now i want to format my PC so i need to install prestashop in my `another PC localhost`. i copied all prestashop files and `database` to my another PC. when i run the prestashop files i'm getting an error "`not found`".

please tell me what i have to do for running prestashop in another localhost.

Comment: You can check your backoffice Preferences->SEO&URLs, .htaccess 

A screenshot would be also helpful

Comment: thanks for your response, i changed url in SE0&URLs now my site is opening but some of images are not displaying.

Comment: may be .htaccess file is not running..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy all prestashop files to your localhost server, import prestashop database to mysql.

first login to prestashop backoffice.

go to Tab Preferences->SEO&URLs check the shop domain, SSL domain is correct or not then goto your front end office.